# function written to reverse linked list doesn't exactly give the right output

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I have a DS assignment where we're supposed to write a program that accepts linked lists, reverses them and prints them out.
now the function itself I think I got right. but the program has to output in a certain way in order to be graded properly which is where I'm struggling.

to demonstrate:
here's the what the sample input and sample output look like 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCwFM.png)

and here's what my output looks like 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QskBo.png)

and of course here's the code (sorry it's kinda long since I wanted to be completely sure. the focus is on ReversePrinter() )

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class SinglyLinkedListNode {

    public:

        int data;

        SinglyLinkedListNode *next;

        SinglyLinkedListNode(int node_data) {

            this->data = node_data;

            this->next = nullptr;

        }

};

class SinglyLinkedList {

    public:

        SinglyLinkedListNode *head;

        SinglyLinkedListNode *tail;

        SinglyLinkedList() {

            this->head = nullptr;

            this->tail = nullptr;

        }

        void insert_node(int node_data) {

            SinglyLinkedListNode* node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data);

            if (!this->head) {

                this->head = node;

            } else {

                this->tail->next = node;

            }

            this->tail = node;

        }

};

void print_singly_linked_list(SinglyLinkedListNode* node, string sep)
{

    while (node) {

        cout << node->data;

        node = node->next;

        if (node) {

            cout << sep;

        }

    }

}

void free_singly_linked_list(SinglyLinkedListNode* node) {

    while (node) {

        SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = node;

        node = node->next;

        free(temp);

    }

}

// Complete the reversePrint function below.

/*

 \* For your reference:

 \*

 \* SinglyLinkedListNode {

 \*     int data;

 \*     SinglyLinkedListNode* next;

 \* };

 \*

 \*/

void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {

    SinglyLinkedListNode* prev = NULL;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode* next_node = head->next;
        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next_node;
    }

    print_singly_linked_list(prev, "\n");


}

int main()

{

    int tests;

    cin >> tests;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for (int tests_itr = 0; tests_itr < tests; tests_itr++) {

        SinglyLinkedList* llist = new SinglyLinkedList();

        int llist_count;

        cin >> llist_count;

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < llist_count; i++) {

            int llist_item;

            cin >> llist_item;

            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            llist->insert_node(llist_item);

        }

        reversePrint(llist->head);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I feel like there's something really simple that I didn't get right but still:)

Comment: Are you sure your program won't get full mark?

Comment: yeah it gives out 0. the way the assignment works is basically it just takes the input and if the output doesn't exactly look like the sample output it doesn't give 100.

Comment: This is not a problem you're asking about but I recommend you to learn and follow good programming practices. Keep your data structures valid – in `reversePrint()` you relink nodes in a reversed order, but you do not update the `head` pointer in the list object; may be your printout is correct, but the list becomes a trash. Separate responsibilities – have a method in a list to reverse it only, and another one to print it. Take care to release memory – add appropriate destructor to the list which deletes nodes, and don't forget to delete the list itself once you no longer use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all output after all input, you should store all of the created lists and then print them.

Also I found one more point: newline is not printed from `reversePrint()` after the last element, so you have to add one after executing that.

It can be done like this:

```
int main()
{
    int tests;
    cin >> tests;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // allocate an array to store lists
    SinglyLinkedList** llists = new SingleyLinkedList*[tests];

    for (int tests_itr = 0; tests_itr < tests; tests_itr++) {
        SinglyLinkedList* llist = new SinglyLinkedList();

        // create list (omit: do just as original code)

        // store created list
        llists[tests_itr] = llist;
        // instead of this
        // reversePrint(llist->head);
    }

    // print created lists
    for (int tests_itr = 0; tests_itr < tests; tests_itr++) {
        // print a list
        reversePrint(llists[tests_itr]->head);
        // print a newline
        cout << '\n';
    }

    // free the array
    delete[] llists;

    return 0;
}
```